# find regex match individually

Tags: python, regex

I have variables in file as which i have to find

```
#define varName      (test_0x5F_u8)
#define varName1      test_0xFF_u16
```

i am unable to match below mentioned expression

```
test_0xFF_u16 and (test_0x5F_u8)
```

- i want to find these variable individually as

  - test is common text and first match
  - 0x5F is second match
  - u8 is third match

Python code

```
re.compile(r'^#define\s+(?i)(\w+)\s+[test_0[xX][0-9a-fA-F][a-z0-9]]+')
```

- search result should give this

  - group(1) = varName
  - group(2) = test_0x5F_u8

it is not finding variable in file. Can any one help me on it.

Comment: You put a sequence into a character class, that does not match whitespaces. What is your expected result? Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS1rD3/1). Or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/gS1rD3/2).

Comment: i tried with this '^#define\s+(?i)(\w+)\s+(test_0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)'. it is working only for 'test_0x5F_u8', not for '(test_0x5F_u8)'

Comment: Try [`^#define\s+(\w+)\s+((?:test_0x[0-9a-fA-F]+_[a-z0-9]+\s+or\s+)?\(test_0x[0-9a-fA-F]+_[a-z0-9]+\))`](https://regex101.com/r/gS1rD3/2). You have not included the requirements, so I am guessing.

Comment: '^#define\s+(\w+)\s+((?:test_0x[0-9a-fA-F]+_[a-z0-9]+\s+or\s+)?\(test_0x[0-9a-f‌​A-F]+_[a-z0-9]+\))' finds expression '#define varName      (test_0x5F_u8)'. it wont find expression '#define varName     test_0x5F_u8'. I need to find both as they are available in file.

Comment: Then use [`^#define\s+(\w+)\s+((?:test_0x[0-9a-fA-F]+_[a-z0-9]+\s+or\s+)?\(?test_0x[0-9a-fA-F]+_[a-z0-9]+\)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/gS1rD3/3) is the parentheses are optional. Are there any more hidden requirements you forgot to include when posting the question? Note they all must be in the question body, otherwise, your question is likely to be downvoted and closed as unclear.

Comment: Thanks, your provided input is working. I have corrected the question hope it will be clear to everyone and useful,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an optional group to match the longer pattern. Also, to use optional parentheses, you need to add `\)?` and `\(?`.

```
^#define\s+(\w+)\s+((?:test_0x[0-9a-f]+_[a-z0-9]+\s+or\s+)?\(?test_0x[0-9a-f]+_[a-z0-9]+\)?)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS1rD3/4). Note it should be used with the `re.I` flag to make matching case-insensitive.

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `#define` - a literal text `#define`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ word chars
- `\s+` - ibid.
- `((?:test_0x[0-9a-f]+_[a-z0-9]+\s+or\s+)?\(?test_0x[0-9a-f]+_[a-z0-9]+\)?)` - Group 2 capturing:

  - `(?:test_0x[0-9a-f]+_[a-z0-9]+\s+or\s+)?` - an optional (1 or 0 times due to `?` at the end) sequence of

    - `test_0x` - `test_0x` substring
    - `[0-9a-f]+` - 1 or more hex chars
    - `_[a-z0-9]+` - an underscore and 1+ alphanumeric chars
    - `\s+or\s+` - `or` enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
- `\(?` - an optional `(`
- `test_0x[0-9a-f]+_[a-z0-9]+` - ibid.
- `\)?` - an optional `)`.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/11IFCc):

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^#define\s+(\w+)\s+((?:test_0x[0-9a-f]+_[a-z0-9]+\s+or\s+)?\(?test_0x[0-9a-f]+_[a-z0-9]+\)?)', re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
s = u"#define varName      test_0x5F_u8 or (test_0x5F_u8)\n#define varName      (test_0x5F_u8)\n#define varName test_0x5F_u8"
print([x for x in p.findall(s)])
// => [(u'varName', u'test_0x5F_u8 or (test_0x5F_u8)'), (u'varName', u'(test_0x5F_u8)'), (u'varName', u'test_0x5F_u8')]
```

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation Wiktor :-)

Comment: If my answer solves your issue please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.compile(r'^#define\s+(?i)(\w+)\s+[test_0[xX][0-9a-fA-F][a-z0-9]]+')
```

there are many things missing in this regex. the opening parentheses, the underscore after 5F, and the last [a-z0-9] will only give one character while in the end you have "u8", which is 2 characters. obviously it won't match.

this should work fine:

```
re.compile(r'^#define\s+(\w+)\s+\(test_0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+_[a-z0-9]+\)')
```

Comment: 're.compile(r'^#define\s+(\w+)\s+\(test_0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+_[a-z0-9]+\)')' works fine for finding expression '#define varName      test_0x5F_u8'. it wont find the expression '#define varName      (test_0x5F_u8)'. i need to find both together.

Comment: check this [link](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%23define%5Cs%2B(%5Cw%2B)%5Cs%2B(%5C(test_0%5BxX%5D%5B0-9a-fA-F%5D%2B_%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%5C))&test_string=%23define%20varName%20%20%20%20%20%20(test_0x5F_u8)&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) please. see if it matches your requirement.